# How to use CreateProcessWithLogonW in c++?

Tags: visual-c++

Below is my code. The function is called, but it does not work. It dont call the exe. Why?

```
int Createprocesslogon()
{
STARTUPINFOW su_info;
ZeroMemory(&su_info, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
su_info.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOW);

PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"xxx", L"localhost", L"123456", 0, L"C:\\Program Files\\app\\IECapt.exe" ,L" --url=http://www.facebook.com/ --out=test.png --min-width=1024", 0, NULL, NULL, &su_info, &pi);

cout << "testt";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean `CreateProcessAsUser`, or `CreateProcessWithToken` after a call to `LogonUser`?

EDIT:
Try this (embedding argument in one):

```
CreateProcessWithLogonW(L"xxx", L"localhost", L"123456", 0, 0,
L"\"C:\\Program Files\\app\\IECapt.exe\" \" --url=http://www.facebook.com/ --out=test.png --min-width=1024\"", 0, NULL, NULL, &su_info, &pi);
```

Comment: [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431.aspx) needs 11 parameters.

Comment: Why do we need to call the LogonUser? What if the admin password is different? how to do?

Comment: @Ben,Corrected. Put entire command line with argument in `lpCommandLine` (6th parameter).
@Kari, Either way you need to pass the username/password,or use `CredUIPromptForCredentials` function.

Comment: I want to open cmd and launch my exe from cmd? 
I'm able to open cmd and able to set its current directory path also but not able to launch my exe. Please help
String applicationName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
String command = "MyExe.exe";
String user = "admin";
String domain = System.Environment.MachineName;
String password = "password";
String currentDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\My Folder\";

using these parameters I'm calling CreateProcessWithLogOnW

Answer (score 0):

`lpCommandLine` is supposed to be the entire command line, starting with the executable (properly quoted).  Otherwise your first argument ends up in `argv[0]` and is ignored by the program.